# Can gems be assigned different interpreters?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, macruby

I fee like I've seen that this was possible in some documentation before, but now I'm not able to find it.  Is it possible to have a gemfile like:

```
gem "somegem", :interpreter => :MRI
gem "othergem", :interpreter => :macruby
```

etc, etc

I am needing this because in macruby some gems do not work, so it'd be great if you could get around that this way.

Comment: Are you looking for the [platforms](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html) parameters? `:platforms => mri_19` and so on. They only alow you to specify which gems to run under the current platform not how to run the gems...

Comment: Yet Another Geek - That's an answer, make it so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the [platforms](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html) parameters? `:platforms => mri_19` and so on. They only alow you to specify which gems to run under the current platform not how to run the gems.

**EDIT**: Anyways if you are not building any Cocoa applications use CRuby (MRI) by default, as it the most complete implementation of Ruby, or try [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) for handling multiple Ruby installations.

Comment: Made it an answer as suggested by Douglas F Shearer.